# VS2015 Breakpoint bind successful but after some rows failed to bind

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm-2016, ilmerge

In one file I can bind breakpoint up to certain position but not after some specific row.

For example I can bind within function first x rows, but trying to set breakpoint further I get "The breakpoint failed to bind". If i step through rows, I can do it only up to the point I can successfully bind.

This is after I merged assembly with ILMerge. Before merge it was working OK. The symbols are loaded successfully (but after I manually right click on module and click Load Symbols). Symbols get loaded that ilmerge has provided.

Using reflection I could verify the class I ILMerged is available (Newtonsoft JSON)

For full picture: Assembly is used within Dynamics CRM and DLL is published to database, if that makes any difference. I am using Remote Debugger if that makes difference.

Where should I dig further? What could cause it to behave like that?

### A picture may be worth thousand words

[image]

### ILMerge details

```
[XrmToolkit v4.5.2.1] -- <Info> -- 29.05.2017. 10:24:06 -- Merging the assemblies using ILMerge...
[XrmToolkit v4.5.2.1] -- <Info> -- 29.05.2017. 10:24:06 -- ILMerge Output Directory: \ILMerge
[XrmToolkit v4.5.2.1] -- <Info> -- 29.05.2017. 10:24:06 -- Using ILMerge to merge assemblies.
[XrmToolkit v4.5.2.1] -- <Info> -- 29.05.2017. 10:24:06 -- ILMerge location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe
[XrmToolkit v4.5.2.1] -- <Info> -- 29.05.2017. 10:24:06 -- ILMerge output path: C:\Users\#removed#\Development\Source\CRM\#removed#\#removed#\bin\Debug\ILMerge\#removed#.dll
[XrmToolkit v4.5.2.1] -- <Info> -- 29.05.2017. 10:24:06 -- ILMerge arguments: /lib:"C:\Users\#removed#\Development\Source\CRM\#removed#\#removed#\bin\Debug" /lib:"C:\Users\#removed#\Development\Source\CRM\#removed#\packages\Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies.8.1.0.2\lib\net452" /lib:"C:\Users\#removed#\Development\Source\CRM\#removed#\packages\Microsoft.CrmSdk.Workflow.8.1.0.2\lib\net452" /target:library /keyfile:"C:\Users\#removed#\Development\Source\CRM\#removed#\#removed#\#removed#.snk" /copyattrs /targetplatform:v4,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5" /closed /log:"C:\Users\#removed#\Development\Source\CRM\#removed#\#removed#\bin\Debug\ILMerge\#removed#.log" /out:"C:\Users\#removed#\Development\Source\CRM\#removed#\#removed#\bin\Debug\ILMerge\#removed#.dll" "C:\Users\#removed#\Development\Source\CRM\#removed#\#removed#\bin\Debug\#removed#.dll" "C:\Users\#removed#\Development\Source\CRM\#removed#\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
```

Comment: I'm assuming you did a clean, then rebuild of your solution?

Comment: @Janis Veinbergs, do you compile your app in debug mode or release mode? Please make sure that you use the latest VS2015 version with update 3.

Comment: @Fletchius, Yes, I did but that doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, Yes, using debug mode. Already on VS15U3 (14.0.25431.01). Remote Debugger is 14.0.25424.0. (Also U3)

Could it be because i'm ILMerging dll from NuGet (Newtonsoft.Json)? Do I have symbols when getting packages from NuGet?

If I do not use ILMerge, debugging works fine.

Comment: @Janis Veinbergs, You could visit the Debug Modules windows and find the assemblies there, maybe you could find the differences before or after you merge the assembly. In addition, just add a breakpoint to the line A before the line B where you couldn't added, and then debug it using F11(Step Into) after the breakpoint A was hit, whether you could step Into B in your side. My understanding is that it would be related to the assembly you merged since you could add the breakpoint before.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, F11 fails. Also I call 3rd party class method multiple lines below where binding fails.

Regarding Debug Modules - you mean that window I have screenshoted? What kind of differences could I see there? :/ I see that correct .pdb file is loaded. But logically thinking: where in the world 3rd party .pdb file can be taken (and merged)? :/

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I think I should just deploy DLLs to GAC for development and merge them for release mode for deployment to CRM. It works that way. Thanks for assistance.

Comment: @Janis Veinbergs, Glad to know that you found a solution for this issue. Maybe you could post the it as the answer and mark it, so it could help other community members who meet the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has something to do with the 3rd party ILMerged assembly.

For debugging to work, I deployed 3rd party assembly to GAC and didn't merge until I want to build a release version for deployment for which debugging isn't necessary.